# How bad is it when my OAuth2.0 tokens will leak?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm going to store user's OAuth2.0 tokens from various sites like Github. If my database leaks (which I hope it will not), how bad is this for the users? Will attackers have full access to their accounts? Revoking all access tokens will be my first step, but I just wanted to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define bad!

Generally the attacker would not have full access to the accounts as tokens generally only offer a limited (scoped) amount of access anyway.

You mention access tokens. You generally wouldn't store access tokens long term as they should be short-lived. You would store refresh tokens though, as they are your means to getting future access tokens without the need of a user.

> Access Tokens.

If you are storing access tokens and someone gains access to them it would mean that they could make use of any token for its lifetime (which isn't usually very long - often an hour or two) so it's bad in the sense that they are usable by anyone (if they are bearer tokens which most are).

If the bearer tokens are reference tokens, or encrypted value tokens, then there's the possibility that the attacker wouldn't know how to use them anyway before they expire. (i.e. they may not know the intended audience of the token).

If the access token is long lived and the attacker knows which resource server it's intended for, then the attacker could potentially use that token and in some cases it will not be possible to revoke the token anyway, so that's quite bad.

> Refresh Tokens.

On their own refresh tokens in the wrong hands are not usable. If however the attacker is able to find out your client id and secret, then they could potentially create new tokens. You'd certainly want to revoke refresh tokens if you can.

Comment: Those was Refresh Tokens what I meant. Thanks for help, I've accepted your answer